# Viewing all photos in a folder in android on the web

Tags: android

I am running a web server and storing all my photos at a folder called photos. Now I want the android application to list all the photos under that particular folder(It can be a slide show or a grid view). I know how to load an image from a url . But I am really unsure about how to view all the images stored on a folder. Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [this](http://www.ethemsulan.com/2011/05/how-to-load-internet-images-in-gridview-android-sample-2.html) for load web images in gridview

And [this](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) to load images from web by lazylist.

To get list of images from your folder. You need to read all file names in that folder by using **FTPClient** and put the filenames as url in the above method.